# Template for Image grid and select

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am working on a website withDjango, and I would like to make a page where:

1. There is a table listing all the images of a model
2. There are two available space two show the images selected by the user

Example:
[image grid display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZX06.jpg)

Currently, in my template I produce the table like that:

```
          <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
          <tr>
              <th>Field 1</th>
              <th>Field 2</th>
              <th>Field 3</th>
          </tr>
          {% for imagemodel in imagemodel %}
          <tr> 
              <td>{{ imagemodel.image }}</td>
              <td>{{ imagemodel.date_taken }}</td>
              <td>{{ imagemodel.image.url }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </table>
```

I don't know what would be the best way to make my wish feasable:

- Is it possible to do that only with javascript ? or only html ?
- Should I work through my django view ?

Many thanks for your help, I am lost :/

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution pure javascript:

```
        var image1 ='';
    var tbl = document.getElementById("galleryTable");

    if (tbl != null) {

        for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {

            for (var j = 2; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)

                tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
        }

    }

    function getval(cel) {
        image1 = tbl.rows[cel.parentNode.rowIndex].cells[2].innerHTML;        
        document.getElementById("2x2_topleft_image_tag").src=image1;
      }
```